# On drop anywhere on body start upload

Tags: dropzone.js

I currently have a dropzone js area like so

```
   <form method="post"
          class="dropzone bg-black"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          action="/">
        <br>
        <div class="normal-form">
            <div class="btn d-inline-block btn-previous">
                <input class="btn"
                       id="files"
                       type="file"
                       name="image"
                       multiple="multiple">
            </div>
            <button class="btn"
                    style="font-size: 20px;"
                    type="submit">Upload
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And my dropzone js configuration looks like so

```
<script defer>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });
    myDropzone.on('drop', function (e) {
        document.querySelector('#files').files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    });
    $('form').on('drop', function () {
        $('form').submit();
    });
    $('form').on('submit', function () {
        $('form').addClass('hidden');
        $('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
    });

</script>
```

As it works, when some one drops a file or files, it hides, shows a upload gif while it uploads the files till uploaded then redirects.

This works fine.  The only issue I'm confused about is how do I make it so if they drop anywhere on the body instead of just the dropzone class, to have that work?

I tried doing

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });
```

but I get

```
Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I had to put in the Dropzone config the url action

```
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
        url: "/",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,

    });
```